# How to specify build options in netbeans IDE 7.4

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I am new to netbeans. I need to add the following build option to my project:

```
mvn -Dhadoop.profile=2.0 package
```

I presume there is some way to specify this in the build options for netbeans, but I am not familiar with that particular IDE.

thanks for your assistance,

Chris

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on your project in the projects list, select `Custom` and then `Goals...`. You should see the `Run Maven` dialog, which in your case you would populate as shown below:

[image]

If you select `Remember as` and type in a name, it will show up with that name in the `Custom` menu.

You can also create global (i.e. not project specific) custom goals by going to `Tools > Options > Java > Maven > Edit Global Custom Goal Definitions...`. You could, for example, define a goal to skip the tests in a build as shown below. These global custom goals will also be displayed in the `Custom` menu.

[image]